# Doxygen brief and detailed descriptions only

Tags: doxygen

I have many projects that all use Doxygen. I document everything and guarantee there are no Doxygen warnings. The output is very nice for getting other developers on board and understanding of the code context.

There is another type of documentation I would like to provide: algorithm description documentation for non-technical people to understand the high level algorithms without extraneous details. Each algorithm has a very verbose detailed description with images where applicable. I would like a version of the Doxygen output with just the brief and detailed descriptions of namespaces and classes without all the functions and interface definitions.

I have parsed though the default Doxyfile to read the descriptions, but haven't seen anything like this. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you readup on the possibilities of the doxxygen layout file, see the chapter "Customizing the output " and especially the part "Changing the layout of pages" (https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout).

Comment: @albert No, I hadn't considered that. I am still new to the layout xml. If `visible="no"` can apply to everything. That is a very good possibility

Comment: This did not work (or I am doing it incorrectly). I added `visible="no"` to many sections, and they still appear, e.g. `<publicmethods visible="no"/>`

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: 1.9.3. For the record, `visible="no"` does work on some things, but not all things

Comment: It looks like that not on all elements in the layout file it is possible to have a "visible" attribute. One of these is "publicmethods". You could remove the tag from the layout file, but as the layout business is quite complex this might have unwanted side effects (like non defined links / pages.

Comment: I did try to remove the tag, but it seems in the absence of the tag, it injects it regardless. Thanks for the help, it is starting to seem like this is not possible. I may just write a Python scanner to extract and prepare the data I need myself.

Comment: The removal of the tag worked for me, I just made a small test case with a class and a method, modified my local `DoxygenLayout.xml` by commenting out the line for publicmethods.

Comment: Ok, I tried again, and was able to make it work. I must have done something wrong the last time. Thanks! I appreciate the help.